# How to replace the values in dataframe using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I want to replace values with some different values in Data frame and this script not working in pandas latest version.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame ([{"Type":"R_NEW","Name":"Rani","Status":"CHANGE"},
                    {"Type":"R_Change","Name":"Venu","Status":"WAIT"}
                    ,{"Type":"PREORDER","Name":"Kiran","Status":"WAIT"}])

df.replace(to_replace={'R_NEW': 'N', 'R_Change': 'C', 'RSD_MOVE': 'M', 'PREORDER': 'P'},
                   value=None, inplace=True,regex= True)

print(df)
```

Expected Output:

```
   Type   Name  Status
0  N      Rani  CHANGE
1  C      Venu    WAIT
2  P      Kiran    WAIT
```

But Getting :

```
   Type     Name  Status
0  R_NEW    Rani  CHANGE
1  R_Change Venu  WAIT
2  PREORDER Kiran WAIT
```

Comment: remove `value=None` parameter

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `value=None` and `regex=True` from the `.replace()` function:

```py
df.replace(
    to_replace={"R_NEW": "N", "R_Change": "C", "RSD_MOVE": "M", "PREORDER": "P"},
    inplace=True,
)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  Type   Name  Status
0    N   Rani  CHANGE
1    C   Venu    WAIT
2    P  Kiran    WAIT
```

Answer (score 1):

If check [`DataFrame.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

> Parameters: **to_replace** str, regex, list, dict, Series, int, float, or None

> Dicts can be used to specify different replacement values for different existing values. For example, {'a': 'b', 'y': 'z'} replaces the value ‘a’ with ‘b’ and ‘y’ with ‘z’. **To use a dict in this way, the optional value parameter should not be given.**

So solution is remove `value=None`:

```
df.replace(to_replace={'R_NEW': 'N', 'R_Change': 'C', 'RSD_MOVE': 'M', 'PREORDER': 'P'},
                   regex= True)
```